# Rewrite old-style classes as new ones

Tags: python, class

I ran pylint on some code and got a complaint about old-style classes.

Can I rectify this by simply changing:

```
class MyClass:
```

to:

```
class MyClass(object):
```

Or is there something more involved?

Comment: That is pretty much it.

Comment: There are a few corner cases where adding `object` to your inheritance tree might break things.  Add it, see if your program breaks in strange ways.  If it does, you did something you probably shouldn't have in the first place :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, writing

```
class MyClass(object):
```

would suffice. Or you switch to Python 3, where

```
class MyClass:
```

would be just fine.

*The inheritance list usually gives a list of base classes (see Customizing class creation for more advanced uses), so each item in the list should evaluate to a class object which allows subclassing. Classes without an inheritance list inherit, by default, from the base class object; hence*

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

*is equivalent to*

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

See also: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class

Also, as @Kevin pointed out in a comment, method resolution is not trivial and might lead to unexpected behavior when using multiple inheritance: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: It will suffice 99% of the time. The [method resolution order](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) rules changed for new-style classes and old code could depend on corner cases that behave differently under those changes.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau, thanks for the link, it was an interesting read.